# Difference between OpenCV type CV_32F and CV_32FC1

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to know if there is any difference between OpenCV types CV_32F and CV_32FC1? 
I already know that 32F stands for a "32bits floating point" and C1 for "single channel", but further explanations would be appreciated.

If yes, how are they different / which one should I use in which specific cases? As you might know that openCV types can get very tricky...

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 54):

The value for both `CV_32F` and `CV_32FC1` is `5` (see explanation below), so numerically there is no difference.

However:

- `CV_32F` defines the depth of each element of the matrix, while
- `CV_32FC1` defines both the depth of each element and the number of channels.

A few examples...

Many functions, e.g. [Sobel](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#sobel) or [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto), require the destination depth (and **not** the number of channels), so you do:

```
Sobel(src, dst, CV_32F, 1, 0);

src.convertTo(dst, CV_32F);
```

But, when creating a matrix for example, you must also specify the number of channels, so:

```
Mat m(rows, cols, CV_32FC1);
```

Basically, every time you should also specify the number of channels, use `CV_32FCx`. If you just need the depth, use `CV_32F`

---

`CV_32F` is defined as:

```
 #define CV_32F  5
```

while `CV_32FC1` is defined as:

```
#define CV_CN_SHIFT   3
#define CV_DEPTH_MAX  (1 << CV_CN_SHIFT)
#define CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK       (CV_DEPTH_MAX - 1)
#define CV_MAT_DEPTH(flags)     ((flags) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK)
#define CV_MAKETYPE(depth,cn) (CV_MAT_DEPTH(depth) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))

#define CV_32FC1 CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,1)
```

which evaluates to `5`.

You can check this with:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout <<  CV_32F << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  CV_32FC1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer, it's clearer now :)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem. Accept it by checking the green tick.