# Iterating through Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator, coordinates, mat

I've got a problem iterating through coordinates of a OpenCV `Mat`:

```
    cv::Mat picture = cv::Mat(depth.rows, depth.cols, CV_32F);

    for (int y = 0; y < depth.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < depth.cols; ++x)
        {
            float depthValue = (float) depth.at<float>(y,x);
            picture.at<float>(y, x) = depthValue;
        }
    }
    cv::namedWindow("picture", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("picture", picture);

    cv::waitKey(0);
```

Resulting pictures:

before (depth)

[image]

after (picture)

[image]

It looks like it's 
1. scaled and 
2. stopped at about a third of the width. Any ideas?

Comment: is depth a cv_32f also ? show us the definition of it please

Comment: Also `CV_32F` is not valid here. You should use `CV_32FC<number of channels>`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37530646/5008845) for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your depth image have 3 channels.

All channels values are the same for BW image `(B=G=R)`, so you have `BGRBGRBGR` instead of `GrayGrayGray`, and you trying to access it as it is 1 channel, that is why image is stretched 3 times horizontally.

Try to `cv::cvtColor(depth,depth,COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` before running loop.

Comment: Most of depth sensor return 3 channels images with depth encoded on two bytes.

Converting the colorspace will definitely loose some data, or even worse, leads to weird result which doesn't express depth anymore.

Comment: It is correct depth channel is usually encoded with 16 or 32 bit channels (CV_16S or CV_32S). But here we have CV_32F so, we can think that it was preprocessed before.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration code is right.
What's wrong instead is the `cv::Mat depth` type assumption.
As suggested, this could be `CV_U8C3` according to the distorsion.
To get the pixel value of such a `CV_8UC3` matrix you can use :

```
cv::Vec3i depthValue = depth.at<cv::Vec3i>(y,x);
```

Then do whatever you want with this scalar.
For example, if your `depth` is of type `CV_8UC3` with distance encoded in the two first bytes (MSB first) you can get the distance with :

```
float distance = depthValue[0] * 255 + depthValue[1];
```