# opencv matrix Pseudo Inverse fails

Tags: c++, opencv

I found a [pinv() example](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/OpenCV/Basics/PseudoInverse) and runs successfully.

But my version fails:

```
Mat1b B = Mat(400, 10, CV_32FC1);
for (r = 0; r < 20; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
    {
        B(n,0) = 1;
        B(n,1) = r;
        B(n,2) = c;
        B(n,3) = r*r;
        B(n,4) = c*r;
        B(n,5) = c*c;
        B(n,6) = r*r*r;
        B(n,7) = c*r*r;
        B(n,8) = c*c*r;
        B(n,9) = c*c*c;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
Mat1b Bpinv = Mat(10, 400, CV_32FC1);
invert(B, Bpinv, DECOMP_SVD);
```

The error in `invert` is:

> Error message like this:OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F) in cv::invert.

It looks like some conflict happens between `CV_32F` and `CV_64F`, but I didn't use `CV_64F` format at all. How could that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `Mat1b` (i.e. a `Mat_<uchar>`, of type `CV_8UC1`), but it should be  `Mat1f` (i.e. a `Mat_<float>`, of type `CV_32FC1`), or `Mat1d` (i.e. a `Mat_<double>`, of type `CV_64FC1`)

You can see then that `CV_8U` is neither `CV_32F` nor `CV_64F`. Please note that the check is only on the depth, not the number of channels.

So the correct code using `Mat_<Tp>` is (either `Mat1f` or `Mat1d`):

```
Mat1f B(400, 10);
for (r = 0; r < 20; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
    {
        B(n,0) = 1;
        B(n,1) = r;
        B(n,2) = c;
        B(n,3) = r*r;
        B(n,4) = c*r;
        B(n,5) = c*c;
        B(n,6) = r*r*r;
        B(n,7) = c*r*r;
        B(n,8) = c*c*r;
        B(n,9) = c*c*c;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}

// You don't have to initialize 'OutputArray' for OpenCV functions
Mat1f Bpinv;
invert(B, Bpinv, DECOMP_SVD);
```

Or, using `Mat`:

```
Mat B(400, 10, CV_32FC1);
for (r = 0; r < 20; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
    {
        B.at<float>(n,0) = 1;
        B.at<float>(n,1) = r;
        B.at<float>(n,2) = c;
        B.at<float>(n,3) = r*r;
        B.at<float>(n,4) = c*r;
        B.at<float>(n,5) = c*c;
        B.at<float>(n,6) = r*r*r;
        B.at<float>(n,7) = c*r*r;
        B.at<float>(n,8) = c*c*r;
        B.at<float>(n,9) = c*c*c;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}

// You don't have to initialize 'OutputArray' for OpenCV functions
Mat Bpinv;
invert(B, Bpinv, DECOMP_SVD);
```

Comment: I understand now. I need to learn more about the format in OpenCV now.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are using type `CV_32FC1`, not `CV_32F`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530646/2628463) to see the difference. I think if you change it to `CV_32F` it should work.