# OpenCV Scalar multiplication gives weird result

Tags: c++, opencv, math

In OpenCV, multiplying two scalars returns unexpected result, for example :

```
cv::Scalar s1(2, 3, 4);
cv::Scalar s2(2, 3, 4);
cv::Scalar s3 = s1 * s2;
```

where I expect s3 should be `[4,9,16,0]` ,however the result is `[-21, 12, 16, 0]`, I would like to know the logic behind it. Thanks!

Comment: Which OpenCV version?

Comment: @kiner_shah 4.5.3

Comment: Since this looks like C++ code, can you add the C++ tag?

Comment: @kiner_shah done !

Comment: Also, are you using this Scalar class present in core/types.hpp? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html

Comment: @kiner_shah No, I am just testing out if the operator * is overloaded .

Comment: I was trying to check the source code to see if it was overloaded, but doesn't look like that. Scalar inherits operator from Vec4 and Vec4 inherits from Mat, that's what I have found so far. You can check using a debugger actually to see which function is being invoked for the operator.

Comment: @kiner_shah how can i trace this ? using gdb ?

Comment: Yes, you can use GDB. You can set a breakpoint appropriately and then step into the function calls. But, you should have the source code available on your system.

Comment: Can you please share the link where you found this?

Comment: @kiner_shah  I found it here :  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/6ffa2b01e1314f686015bb4f80e340bb89eb81f1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L2305

Comment: @kiner_shah And by the way, do you have any idea about where to find the  "range" of data type in opecnv, for example, CV_32F is a float number between 0 to 1 which could easily mess with something like CV_32FC1 .

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530646/4688321

Comment: Also, this link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html

Comment: @kiner_shah the second one looks more complete but I am not able to know the range of data type from this link, right ?

Comment: Actually, those are just flags. So, I think it will be as you said, 32F means a floating point value between 0 and 1. 32FC1 means a floating point value between 0 and 1 but only 1 channel (grayscale image).

Comment: can anyone tell which mathematical vector or matrix operation this is? `(c = (a[0]*b[0] - a[1]*b[1] - a[2]*b[2] - a[3]*b[3]),
                        (a[0]*b[1] + a[1]*b[0] + a[2]*b[3] - a[3]*b[2]),
                        (a[0]*b[2] - a[1]*b[3] + a[2]*b[0] + a[3]*b[1]),
                        (a[0]*b[3] + a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[0]));`

Comment: the indices of a are always 0,1,2,3, but the indices of b seem to *roll* (assuming there's a wraparound/modulo) and reverse. [0 1 2 3], [5 4 3 2], [2 3 4 5], [3 2 1 0] -- a four-dimensional vector, does that have a definition of cross-product? could that be it?

Comment: CV_32F just means single precision float (single channel, CV_32F == CV_32FC1). the range is generally the full range of a 32 bit float. only some functions expect certain value ranges because of the meaning of the input.

Comment: @Micka It seems to be [quaternion product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) (Hamilton)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above I would like to summarize that the source code of `operator*` is defined in [modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/6ffa2b01e1314f686015bb4f80e340bb89eb81f1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L2305) (see below code) and the logic behind it is [quaternion product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

```
template<typename _Tp> static inline
Scalar_<_Tp> operator * (const Scalar_<_Tp>& a, const Scalar_<_Tp>& b)
{
    return Scalar_<_Tp>(saturate_cast<_Tp>(a[0]*b[0] - a[1]*b[1] - a[2]*b[2] - a[3]*b[3]),
                        saturate_cast<_Tp>(a[0]*b[1] + a[1]*b[0] + a[2]*b[3] - a[3]*b[2]),
                        saturate_cast<_Tp>(a[0]*b[2] - a[1]*b[3] + a[2]*b[0] + a[3]*b[1]),
                        saturate_cast<_Tp>(a[0]*b[3] + a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[0]));
}
```